# MySQL and python-mysql (mysqldb) crashing under heavy load

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, fastcgi, mysql-python

I was just putting the finishing touches to a site built using web.py, MySQL and python-mysql (mysqldb module) feeling good about having projected from sql injections and the like when I leant on the refresh button sending 50 or so simultaneous requests and it crashed my server! I reproduced the error and found that I get the following two errors interchangeably, sometimes its one and sometimes the other:

Error 1:

```
127.0.0.1:60712 - - [12/Sep/2013 09:54:34] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 500 Internal Server Error
Exception _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x10b287750>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Error 2:

```
python(74828,0x10b625000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd8991b6e00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Clearly the requests are straining MySQL and causing it to fall over so my question is how do I protect against this happening.

My server setup is setup using Ubuntu 13.04, nginx, MySQL (which I connect to with the mysqldb python module), web.py and fast-cgi.

When the web.py app starts up it connects to the database as so:

```
def connect():
    global con 
    con = mdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWORD, db=DATABASE)

    if con is None:
        print  'error connecting to database'
```

and the con object is assigned to a global variable so various parts of the application can access it

I access the databse data like this:

```
def get_page(name):
    global con 
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()    
        cur.execute("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='jt_website' AND `TABLE_NAME`='pages'")
        table_info = cur.fetchall()
```

One idea I had was to open and close the database before and after each request but that seems overkill to me, does anybody have any opinions on this?

What sort of methods do people use to protect their database connections in python and other environments and what sort of best practices should I be following?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use `web.py` but docs and tutorials show a different way to deal with database.

They suggest to use a global object (you create it in `.connect`) which probably will be a `global proxy` in the `Flask` style.

Try organizing your code <s>as in [this example](http://webpy.org/src/todo-list/0.3) ←DEAD LINK</s> and see if it happens again.

The error you reported seems a concurrency problem, that normally is handled automatically by the framework.

About the latter question:

> What sort of methods do people use to protect their database connections in python and other environments and what sort of best practices should I be following?

It's different depending on the web framework you use. Django for example hides everything and it just works.
[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) lets you choose what you want to do. You can use `flask-sqlalchemy` which uses the very good [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) ORM managing the connection proxy for the web application.

Comment: I'm not sure what they do to prevent these errors but it worked, I'd be curius to know how its handles

Comment: @jonathantopf for some insights on how proxies works in the Flask Werkzeug you can look at this: http://pynash.org/2013/02/12/proxy-objects.html